# What is the number of ways to arrange people in a queue?

Tags: combinatorics

People are standing in a queue when viewed from the front, m heads are visible, and n heads from the end. What is the number of possible arrangements such that m&n remains same when viewed from front and end respectively.

The number of people is P and it is not necessary that m+n=P

Comment: The way I read this is that there is a subsequence of $m$ progressively taller people when seen from the front of the line and a subsequence of $n$ progressively taller people when seen from the rear of the line.

Comment: @user12331 Have you assumed that "***everyone in the queue is either facing forward or facing backwards***" ?

Comment: @Famke. They are all facing forward

Comment: @user12331: Are the $P$ people required to have pairwise distinct heights?

Comment: @quasi. No they don't need to

Answer (score 1):

At first let's **ignore** the peoples whose faces are visible from the end;
and assume that all faces are visible from front.

**By the above assumption**;
if we only consider the place of peoples, then we have $(m+n)!$ possibilities.

---

Notice that we have ${m+n \choose n}$ posibilities to choose the peoples;
whose faces are visible when they are viewed from front.
[We choose $n$ people and call them to turn their face away.]

---

So we have ${m+n \choose n} \cdot (m+n)!$ posibilities.

Comment: It appears that you're assuming everyone in the queue is either facing forwards or facing backwards, and that visibility only depends on which way a person is facing. If so, your answer makes sense (+1). But a more natural interpretation of the question is that everyone is facing forwards and that visibility depends only on relative height (i.e., a person is visible from the front if and only if they are taller than anyone in front of them). Based on that interpretation, the number of people in the queue needs to be specified.

Comment: @quasi ; Yes I have been supposed that "everyone in the queue is either facing forward or facing backwards" .

Comment: @user12331 ; by this assumption, this answer works.

Comment: Yes, agreed, but note -- the problem used the term "heads", not "faces", so it's not clear that you have the intended interpretation. Nevertheless, _assuming_ your interpretation, the answer you gave is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(m,n,p)$ be the number of ways to order $p\;$people in a queue such that exactly $m\;$heads are visible from the front, and exactly $n\;$heads are visible from the back.

If the heights are not pairwise distinct, knowing the values of $m,n,p\;$is not sufficient to find $f(m,n,p)$.

For example, if there are exactly $t\;$people with max height, but all other heights are pairwise distinct, then
$$
f(1,2,5)=
\begin{cases}
6,&\text{if}\;\,t=1\\
11,&\text{if}\;\,t=2\\
5,&\text{if}\;\,t=3\\
1,&\text{if}\;\,t=4\\
0,&\text{if}\;\,t=5\\
\end{cases}
$$
More generally, if the heights are not required to be pairwise distinct, then to compute $f(m,n,p)$, you would need to know the exact multiplicities of the heights for each rank (shortest to tallest). It's not enough to just know $m,n,p$.

So let's assume the heights are pairwise distinct.

Then for positive integers $m,n,p$, we have
$$f(m,n,p) = \sum_{k=1}^p 
{\small{\binom{p-1}{k-1}}}
g({\small{m-1,k-1}})
g({\small{n-1,p-k}})
$$
where $g(m,p)$ is defined recursively, for nonnegative integers $m,p$, by
$$
g(m,p) =
\begin{cases}
0,\;\;\;\text{if}\;\,m>p\\[3pt]
0,\;\;\;\text{if}\;\,m = 0\;\;\text{and}\;\;p>0\\[3pt]
1,\;\;\;\text{if}\;\,m = 0\;\;\text{and}\;\;p=0\\[2.5pt]
{\displaystyle{\sum_{j=1}^p{\small{\binom{p-1}{j-1}}}g({\small{m-1,j-1}}){\small{(p-j)!}}}},\;\;\;\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Some sample values . . .
\begin{align*}
f(2,3,4)&=3\\[4pt]
f(2,4,5)&=4\\[4pt]
f(3,4,6)&=10\\[4pt]
f(4,6,10)&=2016\\[4pt]
f(10,10,30)&=3046341296618108116828200\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

I interpret this to mean that you want to count the number of possible queues of a set of P people such that when viewed by some observer on the left (in the plane of the queue) there are $m$ visible heads and when viewed from the right there are $n$ visible heads.

Now, I am aware of your comment that states that the people need not have pairwise distinct heights, however I will solve (as @quasi has done) for the case where everyone in the queue has distinct heights. This will serve as a platform from which we can reach the "non-distinct heights" case.

To turn this into a combinatorial problem we will be counting permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots ,P\}$ such that there are $m$ integers which are greater than all those on their left and $n$ integers that are greater than all those on their right. So, for example one permutation of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is

$$\require{enclose}\begin{array}{cccccc}
\enclose{circle}{2}&1&\enclose{circle}{5}&4&\enclose{roundedbox}{\enclose{circle}{6}}&\enclose{roundedbox}{3}\end{array}$$

where $\enclose{circle}{\phantom{5}}$ highlights a visible "head" from the left and $\enclose{roundedbox}{\phantom{5}}$ highlights a visible "head" from the right.

We can use generating functions to enumerate these. Let $x$ be the enumerator for visible heads from the left and $y$ be the enumerator for visible heads from the right then start by placing the largest integer in the set $\{1,2,\ldots , P\}$.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}\bullet&P&\bullet\end{array}$$

this possibility adds a single count to each $x$ and $y$ enumerator and therefore is represented by

$$xy$$

Next place the next largest integer $P-1$, this may go to the left of $P$, where it will add a count of $1$ to the $x$ enumerator, or to the right of $P$, where it will add a count of $1$ to the $y$ enumerator. Let's pick the left side:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}\bullet&(P-1)&\bullet&P&\bullet\end{array}$$

This contributes a factor $(x+y)$ so our generating function so far is

$$xy(x+y)$$

Next place $P-2$. It may go to the left where it contributes $x$, right where it contributes $y$, or between $P$ and $P-1$ where it will contribute neither to the $x$ or $y$ enumerators. So in this last case it is represented by $1$. For arguments sake let's place $P-2$ to the right of $P$:

$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}\bullet&(P-1)&\bullet&P&\bullet&(P-2)&\bullet\end{array}$$

These possibilities contribute a factor $(1+x+y)$ to our generating function giving:

$$xy(x+y)(1+x+y)$$

The next integer to be placed is $P-3$ and this contributes $x$ if placed to the left of $P-1$, $y$ if placed to the right of $P-2$ or $1$ if placed at either of the $2$ positions in-between contributing a factor $(2+x+y)$ hence the generating function is now

$$xy(x+y)(1+x+y)(2+x+y)$$

as this pattern continues we get the required generating function which is a [rising factorial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

$$g_P(x,y)=xy(x+y)^{(P-2)}\tag{1}$$

so your desired result for the distinct height case is the $x^ny^m$ coefficient of $g_P(x,y)$.

The form of $(1)$ may look familiar to the generating function for [Stirling Numbers of the First Kind](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) and a simple expansion will show that

$$[x^ny^m]g_P(x,y)=\binom{n+m-2}{n-1}{P-1 \brack n+m-2}\tag{2}$$

---

**A start on the non-distinct heights case**

To generalise this to non-distinct heights we must know how many people of each height there are. In this case the problem is equivalent to permuting the multiset $\{1,1,\ldots , 1, 2,2,\ldots , 2,\ldots , P,P,\ldots ,P\}$ and counting those where n integers are greater than all those on their left and $m$ are greater than all those on their right. If their are $n_i$ occurrences of the integer $i$ in the multiset then we are permuting $N=\sum_{i=1}^{P}n_i$ integers.

The process is similar to before only this time at each stage the factor for the generating function will be (using a stars and bars argument):

$$\binom{n_{P-k}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n_{P-i}-2}{n_{P-k}}+\binom{n_{P-k}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n_{P-i}-2}{n_{P-k}-1}x+\binom{n_{P-k}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n_{P-i}-2}{n_{P-k}-1}y+\binom{n_{P-k}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n_{P-i}-2}{n_{P-k}-2}xy$$

and hence the generating function will be the product of these and the $xy$ term representing the single placement of the $n_P$ replicas of $P$

$$xy\times\prod_{k=1}^{P-1} \left(\binom{n_{P-k}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n_{P-i}-2}{n_{P-k}}+\binom{n_{P-k}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n_{P-i}-2}{n_{P-k}-1}x+\binom{n_{P-k}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n_{P-i}-2}{n_{P-k}-1}y+\binom{n_{P-k}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n_{P-i}-2}{n_{P-k}-2}xy\right)$$